# Issues putting a table inside a form in a jQuery Mobile environment

Tags: html, forms, jquery-mobile, html-table

So I'm currently having issues putting an HTML table inside a form within a jQuery Mobile environment.

The error I get is as follows: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'not' of undefined**

And here's the line that it points me to within **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js:13906** in the Chrome debugger:
[image: jQueryMobileProblemSection]

Lastly here is the code for the table and form I am attempting to create:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">

    <table data-role='table'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="company" form="my_form"></td>
                <button type="button" form="my_form">ok</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I've also noticed that this particular error is only triggering once the td element is placed inside the table, **therefore if I were to comment out the td tags and content and keep the table and tr elements,  no error is triggered.**

Please help.

Comment: The error suggests that `var cells = $(this).jqmData("cells")` failed.

Comment: First question, when calling `.jqmData("cells")`, `cells` is not a correct selector of a JQuery object.  I would expect a class or id selected like `.cells` or `#cells`. What are you trying to select?

Comment: Or are you confusing the `this`? Did you try `var = table.jqmData("cells")`?

Comment: I'm not using those commands at all, all of that is being pulled from the jQuery mobile source code. 

The only code I'm using that's triggering this is there in my table and form code.

Comment: This might be a bug in JQM 1.4.5. I am encountering the error as well in FireFox: `TypeError: f is undefined: jquery.....min.js (line 8, col 18418)`. Here is my test: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/whwmsp2c/ if I remove the `data-role="table"`, it renders the table. You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/whwmsp2c/3/

Comment: I switched to the uncompressed version and get much more detail: `TypeError: cells is undefined: hierarchyClass = cells.not( this ).filter( "thead th" ).length && " ui-table-cel... jquery.....4.5.js (line 13906, col 5)`, testing done here: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/whwmsp2c/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work by including the `thead`. See working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/whwmsp2c/5/

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header"><h2>Test Form</h2></div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" data-ajax="false" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="myForm">
            <table id="myTable" data-role="table" data-mode="reflow">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="html" form="myForm" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" form="myForm" >ok</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I reviewed all the docs and looked at the error, I could see that your HTML did not have a header for the table, and JQM was looking for this. By adding it, the table renders fully.

See more: http://api.jquerymobile.com/table/

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late confirmation but I ended up dropping this and then had to come back to it for a completely different reason and this works!